# Outline turns INline - Chrome bug I think

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Can anyone tell me why the hell is this happening in Google Chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiago/D2jLr/

An outline means that is a line that is outside something right? When I focus on my input my outline turns an "inline". It shouldn't right? This is happening in several projects I'm working on. I'm using Chrome 19.0.1084.52 m.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

It just looks like that. Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D2jLr/1/) I made the lines thicker. The outline is still on the outside.

It moving in 1px looks to be just a Chrome bug.. you can sort of work around it by switching the border and outline colors on focus.

```
input:focus { border: 1px solid red; outline: 1px solid orange;}
```

It still moves in 1px but the order of the colors is maintained at least.

Comment: It works but only if the line is thicker like you said. And when you focus the input, the outline contracts about 1 pixel - enough to mess all up, when I'm working with thin lines

Comment: I think the best solution is using the box-shadow property. It doesn't work in all browsers but at least gets prettier I think.

Comment: Yeah, although there ways of [box shadow in IE](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2011/08/24/how-to-simulate-css3-box-shadow-in-ie7-8-without-javascript/). Not pretty (code wise), but it might help.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome changes `outline-offset` (which controls the location of the outline) on focus.

Simply use `outline: 1px solid blue; outline-offset: 0;` and it'll work the way you want it to.

Answer (score -1):

Chrome's outline border is slightly thicker than the border of your input causing it to look like it's on the inside.  If this is annoying, you can turn of chrome's outline by:

```
outline:none;
```

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/D2jLr/2/

Comment: He already has a custom outline. The issue is that the outline moves in 1px when the input box is in focus, making it look like an "inline" rather than an outline since it appears to be inside the border.

Comment: I want the border to be always there. Why should it be different when on normal and focus mode? I'm already defining the width of the outline by doing "1px solid".